# Which TLS/SSL version does Amazon MQ client uses to connect to brokers?

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic, tls1.2, amazon-mq

In `Amazon MQ`, when we connect from `Active MQ` client to `Amazon MQ` broker, we just use connection URL as `ssl://<broker>:61617` but nowhere in whole AWS documentation it mentioned if this client-broker communication is secure or not and which version of `TLS` does client-broker connection use. Below is sample snippet of code to connect Amazon MQ as provide by AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-connecting-application.html).

```java
// Create a connection factory.
final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(wireLevelEndpoint);

// Pass the username and password.
connectionFactory.setUserName(activeMqUsername);
connectionFactory.setPassword(activeMqPassword);

// Create a pooled connection factory.
final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(10);

// Establish a connection for the producer.
final Connection producerConnection = pooledConnectionFactory.createConnection();
producerConnection.start();
```

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57187966/11338849) says it uses `SSL` but no mention, which version of `TLS/SSL` it uses as old `SSL` is no more secure.

Which TLS/SSL version does `Amazon MQ` broker - client connection use? Do we have any othe way to use latest version of TLS with `Amazon MQ` broker - client?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon recommend TLS 1.2 or later.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/data-protection.html

Comment: And to piggyback here, it looks like the specific options you want can be set as part of the URI:
http://activemq.apache.org/ssl-transport-reference. 

That page notes that "From version 5.4 any SSLServerSocket option may be set on a TransportConnection via ?transport.XXX"

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).